# Why does my SQL Statement Display data into a table before I specify the output date from the date-picker

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server-2008

I have a problem that I'm trying to solve a while ago.
 I have a table that displays the No-visit company names and suburbs.
Therefore, I'm using 2 select statement in a single SQL query to get the output that I want. And the I can see my data from a table I select the date range from the date-picker.

Now MY PROBLEM IS: I Don't want to see data populate automatically into the table by itself.
Whenever I go to the page, there are already data displaying in the table without me selecting the date from the date picker.

Is there a way to fix this problem?
Please advice.

This is my SQL Statement that I believe is the problem but I don't know how to solve it.

```
SELECT Name, Suburb 
FROM Client_table, user
     WHERE Client_Id NOT IN 
           (SELECT Distinct client_fk AS callesmade FROM Visits_table
           WHERE Start_Date >= '".$Fdate."')
AND 
    Branch = area
AND username = '".$_SESSION["username"]."'
ORDER BY Suburb, Name"
```

**What is the problem from my SQL Statement?**

Please someone help!

Thank you

Comment: Are you running both MySQL and SQL Server?

Comment: @Jarlh, my current problem is on the SQL Statement! It's for MySQL but sooner I will use almost the same query for SQL Server!

Comment: Sounds like your php code to select data is running when you don't want it to. Should be fairly easy to debug if you step through your php code.

Comment: @Allan, I can i step through my code? Please if you have a subjection please feel free to answer me. Thank you in advance

Comment: I mean your php code is likely calling your sql statement at a time where you're not intested in it, from your description, and it's that code you should step through (php, not sql)

Comment: I Got you now @Allan, I will try to double-check on my php code now. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want that on loading first time of page or refreshing the your table should be load blank then you can use this condition

```
if(isset($Fdate) && $Fdate !='')
{
SELECT Name, Suburb FROM Client_table, user WHERE Client_Id NOT IN (SELECT Distinct client_fk AS callesmade FROM Visits_table WHERE Start_Date >= '".$Fdate."') AND Branch = area AND username = '".$_SESSION["username"]."' ORDER BY Suburb, Name"
}
```

This condition will check that if user has select the date from datepicker then it will fire the query.

Comment: Thank you very much @Sunil, The table refresh and it's blank when I first open the page. but There is an error message that says: Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource,  What does it mean?

Comment: I suggest you to put your all query in this if condition your mysql_num_rows also. This will solve your problem.

Comment: Yes! Yes! You are totally right, Everything work smoothly now. Thank you very much! You have just save my day!

Answer (score 0):

Probably the old NOT IN problem... Beware of NULL's from the sub-select, because if you have any the NOT IN will be false, and your query will return 0 rows.

For example you can use NOT EXISTS instead:

```
SELECT Name, Suburb
FROM Client_table, user
WHERE Client_Id NOT IN (SELECT client_fk
                        FROM Visits_table
                        WHERE client_fk = Client_Id AND Start_Date >= '".$Fdate."')
 AND Branch = area AND username = '".$_SESSION["username"]."'
 ORDER BY Suburb, Name"
```

Or just make sure no client_fk is null:

```
SELECT Name, Suburb
FROM Client_table, user
WHERE Client_Id NOT IN (SELECT client_fk
                        FROM Visits_table
                        WHERE client_fk IS NOT NULL
                          and Start_Date >= '".$Fdate."')
  AND Branch = area
  AND username = '".$_SESSION["username"]."'
ORDER BY Suburb, Name
```

Comment: I understand. but I would like to know if there is any other way to change the  "NOT IN" to something else! or any other format! Thanks

Comment: @Jardh, I tried but I still getting the error at the opening of the page: '"Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource" How to get rid of this error message?